# Gradle replace token in a file during build process

Tags: build.gradle

I have a web application and I use gradle to build it. In one of the xml files in WEB-INF folder (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/my.xml) I have a piece of file that needs replacing.

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="clientId" value="@clientId@" />
</system-properties>
```

When I try to replace the token with some value using:

```
processResources{
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:['clientId': 'test'])
}
```

Than when I run `gradle build` the token in the output file `(./build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/my.xml)` is not replaced. I was wondering which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are configuring the wrong task. `processResources` only copies files from src/main/resources (or whatever else you define in the main sourceSet as resource), while it is task `war` which copies / zips your `my.xml`.

```
war {
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:['clientId': 'test'])
}
```

Comment: Note that `ReplaceTokens` requires adding `import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens` to `build.gradle`. See the [Copy DSL docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) for more details and another example.

Comment: How do I do this **only for specific file extension**, e.g. `*.xml`?