# Spring - Is it possible to resolve properties (such as environment variables) recursively in properties file?

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, spring-properties

I am using `@PropertySource` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to load my properties file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
class MyApp {
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

In `app.properties`, I would like to have:

```
database.dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:${db-port:5432}/mydb
```

Here, the port of the database is either resolved from the property `db-port`, or defaulted to 5432.

This would allow me to spawn my application with the `-Ddb-port=9876` flag if necessary. If this flag is not set, the default port as written in `app.properties` should be taken.

Comment: We currently do something similar via `ReplaceTokens`. You could likely do this the same way. This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247193/gradle-replace-token-in-a-file-during-build-process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible, according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779883/4785937